# Why did I apparently get +97 for joining a site?

Tags: support, achievements-dialog

Don't worry! I got all my 100 reputation :) It just didn't appear that way...

[image: +97 rep]

The notification says +100, but why does it say +97 at the top?

**Edit**

I created an account on server fault, and this time it says +96. I assume it's because of the down votes on this question; however, I thought down votes aren't shown in the rep you gain.

Comment: Did you downvote answers elsewhere today? Or any downvotes to your posts?

Comment: What is wrong??

Comment: @bluefeet No, I didn't

Comment: The -29 caused the number to disappear then it showed up again only when the delta from last click was positive. If you would have got a question upvote before joining the new site, you would have seen a +2 instead of +97

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All posts highlighted blue are reflected in the ***net*** `+97`

```
+100
+2
+5
+3
+2
+5
-29
+10
```

Adding those up I get `+98`. Presumably there's a `-1` somewhere out of view.

Every time you click the Achievements icon, the count resets and "unread" items are cleared, so you're looking at reputation changes from the past week.

Reputation increases trigger an achievements notification. But because of the `-29`, your net reputation since the dialog was last opened had been negative. Once you received the association bonus, that pushed it positive, to the `+97` you saw

Answer (score 3):

Not only your assoc bonus is showing, all thats blue is unread. Sum up all the unread values (scroll down also) and you get 97.